# Bootstrap 4 navbar with fullscreen mobile menu background jumping when opened

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have the following navbar that, when open on mobile, should have a background that covers the entire screen.

The problem is that with my current implementation the contents of the navbar "jumps" down the screen a little bit. I want the navbar-brand and the links to remain where they would without jumping.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypcrumble/s51d06k6/876/) for an example showing the code I've tried and the current problem.

Removing the `height: 100vh` directive removes the "jump", but then the background of the open mobile navbar no longer covers the entire viewport, which is what I want without the jumping.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: can try this property `.nav.navbar-nav{height: 100vh;}`  or  remove `nav.open{height: 100vh;}`

Comment: please check https://jsfiddle.net/s51d06k6/882/  Hope this help

Comment: @jaydeeppatel thank you! Doing both of those together worked!

Comment: Hope to upvote .

Comment: @jaydeeppatel you should post your comment as an answer and I can mark it as correct and upvote that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4 - Fullscreen mobile navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892380/bootstrap-4-fullscreen-mobile-navbar)